# searching and saving specifing links in html code

Tags: java, string, search, image, bufferedreader

```
</div><div class="tr">
  </div><div class="bl">
  </div><div class="br">
  </div>  <img src="http://blablabla.com/medium/blablabla.jpg" />
</div></a>
          </div><div class="meta">
<h3 class="action">
<span>
    <a href="/abc">ABC</a>
  </span> a picture
</h3>
```

I saves a website's HTML source code into String with following:

```
  public static BufferedReader read(String url) throws Exception
  {
    return new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            new URL(url).openStream()));
  }
```

In this code I want to save all image urls in a new String wih concating \n which has **/medium/** inside OR to make easier all image links in a string with concating \n.
how should be the process? thanks in advance

Comment: I would use a regex to find the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than attempting to parse the HTML content yourself, you could use [JSoup](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) to get the image tags and do a simple `String.contains` to get the image tags you are looking for.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.blah.com/foo.html");
for (Element e : doc.select("img")) {
    String imageSrc = e.attr("src");
    if (imageSrc.contains("/medium/")) {
     ...
    }
}
```

Also [avoid using regex to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: Which one should be imported for "Document doc = ..": org.w3c.dom or org.jsoup.nodes ? and I guess I have to typecast Jsoup.conne.. to (Document)

Comment: [org.jsoup.nodes.Document](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html)...